# How to read specific special character

Tags: java, string

I have a string like

```
Str s1 = abd,jh
Str2 = aa$$ab
```

I want to read string which have only a,b and $.

```
Str1 return false
Str2 return true.
```

My Code

```
public static boolean containsOtherCharacter(String str) {
        String[] st = str.split("");
        for(int x = 0; x < st.length; x++)
            if (st[x].compareTo("A") != 0 && st[x].compareTo("B") != 0 && st[x].compareTo("$") != 0)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Any help how to read that. Any other value other then this should be ignored.

Comment: so what is special about special character. Loop the string, check the characters and compare it can be one crude way.

Comment: a regex akin to `[^ab$]+` will indicate if there are any other characters. Use an online regex tester to fully develop and validate the regex.

Comment: @Turing85 I updated my question.

Comment: WRT to the code: you can loop a String using `str.length()` and `str.charAt(i)` -- no need to do the array via a split. You also seem to only be comparing upper case characters.

Comment: And you may want to swap `return true;` with `return false;`.

Comment: @Turing85 even after swaping I am getting "Incorrect" all the time.

Comment: Look at [Chandler Bing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a working solution.

Comment: @shankysingh Do you want to read the `String` that contains `a`, `b` and `$`?

Comment: @Yahya yes. for other character it will return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to overcomplicate things here. You could simply use a regular expression, like

```
String s = "aa$$ab";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[ab$]", "").length()==0);
```

It removes `a`, `$`, and `b` from the `String`. After that, if the length is greater than 0, then the String must have had some other characters.**Note** that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Serious question: is doing a regex replace or a regex match faster? Cool solution.

Comment: I want to just check whether string only these three character or other than else. Don't want to replace from `""` and making length to 0.

Comment: I am using this `if (st[x].compareToIgnoreCase("A") != 0 && st[x].compareToIgnoreCase("B") != 0 && st[x].compareToIgnoreCase(".") != 0)`

Comment: @shankysingh You know that [`String`s are immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), do you?

Comment: @shankysingh `replaceAll`  does what you want. It doesn't replace the orignal String. Print it out if you don't believe. String are immutable. They don't change once assigned.

Comment: ya.. I tested that. Thanks for answer. It is working. yes I got that string is immutable.

Comment: @ChandlerBing Thanks. Working like charm. I changed my functioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean hasSpecialChar( String input)
 {
    boolean found = true;
   int len = input.length();
   for(int i = 0; i< len ; i++)
   {
      if(input.charAt(i)== 97|| input.charAt(i)==98 ||input.charAt(i)==36)
      {
         // read the string 
         }
         else 
         {
            found = false;
            return found;
            // give out the error
            }
      }
      return found ;

    }
```

As you want to only read the a, b and $ thus we could use the ASCII values of the character and thus read in the string or line character by character and check the input. As the ASCII values for a is equal to 97, 98 for b and 36 for $ this would work fine for this case. 
Hope is helps you!!! @shanky singh

Comment: You should really use the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'&'` rather than the integer codes. Far easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah that could be another solution to this problem, as there are many ways to solve the same problem. Thanks for adding an other approach to this solution.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You didn't add any comment above your `if(input.charAt` line indicating which characters you've indicated by integer code , so users would have to go look up the ASCII value if they wanted to understand what you've written. It's a matter of poor coding style, not an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this:

```
public static boolean containsOtherCharacter(String str) {
           boolean The_answer=false;
           int count0 = StringUtils.countMatches(str, "a");
           int count1 = StringUtils.countMatches(str, "b");
           int count2 = StringUtils.countMatches(str, "$");
           int ans=count0+count1+count2;

           if(ans==str.length())The_anser=true;

           return The_answer;
   }
```